# Am i inserting my form right? Php form to mysql Database

Tags: php, forms, submit

Hello im having Some trouble with my php script, im trying to make it were you can insert information to a Database anyone have any suggestions?

Form html

```
<form action="input.php" method="post">
    Title: <br /><input type="text" name="title"><br /><br />
    Value (Start): <br /><input type="text" name="objectv"><br /><br />
    Value (End): <br /><input type="text" name="objectvv"><br /><br />
    Originated: <br /><input type="text" name="objecto"><br /><br />
    Number: <br /><input type="text" name="objectn"><br /><br />
    Category: <br /><input type="text" name="category"><br /><br />
    Imagine: <br /><input type="text" name="image"><br /><br />
    <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Submit C-Object">
</form>
```

input.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("----","----","----");//database connection
mysql_select_db("-----");

//inserting data order
 $sql="INSERT INTO cobjectsel (id, entry, object_range, brand, model, rocker_type, flex, size_range, image)
VALUES
    ('','$_POST[title]',$_POST[objectv],$_POST[objecto],$_POST[objectn],$_POST[category],$_POST[objectvv],<img src=''$_POST[image]' width=''100'' height=''100''>,0)";

//declare in the order variable
$result = mysql_query($order);  //order executes
if($result){
    echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
} else{
    echo("<br>Input data is fail");
}
?>
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cobjectsel (
  id int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  entry varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  object_range int(10) NOT NULL,
  brand varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  model varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  rocker_type varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  flex varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  size_range varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  image varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY id (id)
)
```

Comment: No, you aren't. That code is wiiiide open to SQL injection. Also, `mysql` has been deprecated. You should be using mysqli or pdo.

Comment: make sure to enclose all the string values with single quote.

Comment: And please use the html `<label>` tags for your input label.

Comment: You should also apply CSS.  Multiple `<br />`'s are bad form.  Try using `<div>` or `<p>` with padding or margin.

Comment: For starters if your ID is auto incremented and primary, you should not have to include that in the insert. You will need quotes around the names in the `$_POST` global variable. **MYSQL FUNCTIONS HAVE BEEN DEPRECATED. USE MYSQLI OR PDO WITH PREPARED STATEMENTS FOR NOT SQL INJECTION.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the image tag as a string

```
<img src=''$_POST[image]' width=''100'' height=''100''>
```

should be

```
... , '<img src="'.$_POST[image].'" width="100" height="100">', ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your SQL query. replace your `$sql` with this:

```
   //inserting data order
 $sql="INSERT INTO `cobjectsel` (`entry`, `object_range`, `brand`, `model`, `rocker_type`, `flex`, `size_range`, `image`) VALUES('$_POST[title]', '$_POST[objectv]', '$_POST[objecto]', '$_POST[objectn]', '$_POST[category]', '$_POST[objectvv]', '<img src=\"$_POST[image]\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\">', '0')";
```

And then replace `$order` with `$sql` like this:

```
//declare in the order variable
$result = mysql_query($sql);  //order executes
```

Comment: Thanks a ton but im geting a In Out data is a fail error and when i check phpmyadmin nothing is written..Could it be my Table?

Answer (score 0):

Here are you passing image tag instead of this you can pass only image name.